# can I make my home network look like my work network

Tags: network

We have to sign in and out using the school's network. I have the ssid and the password and the ip addresses. Is there a way to use my home network and make them think I am using the school's network? I think it might be possible but can't figure it out. We all sign in on time but they make us stay 2 hours after everyone has gone and it seems unfair and a waste of time.

Comment: Questions on how to bypass security measures for your personal gain are off-topic here. Moreover, it is not clear how they specifically monitor you. But if is is about your device being present in their WiFi network then you cannot emulate this presence from remote.

Comment: You may want to consider connecting a device (e.g. an old laptop, or mini computer, or even a raspberry pi) to your work network, that you can access remotely from home via SSH, RDP, or some other protocol.  If hole-punching through your work network's firewall is a problem, you may want to consider accessing the device through Tor by running a Tor hidden service on the device.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/260136/how-to-set-up-a-restricted-account-for-reverse-ssh-port-forwarding-in-a-safe-way for more info.